# how to change logout dialog facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, dialog

I have app with loginButton. When I press Logout a dialog with confirmation appears.
It is possible to change i.e. text in appearing dialog? If is please tell me how to do that. I need to translate text to other language.

[image]

Comment: If it's not possible, search for how to manually kill your session with Facebook and create your own dialog.

Comment: a jak byś zmienił wartości w res/values/strings.xml? albo dodał res/values-pl/strings.xml i tam przetłumaczył? tylko to trzeba by było zrobić w projekcie facebook sdk nie w swoim ... przykład z hiszpańskim https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/res/values-es/strings.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As facebook sdk comes as android library project you can do this by translating [`strings.xml`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/res/values/strings.xml) from `/res/values`(of android sdk project) and putting it to `/res/values-xx` (where xx can be fx. `pl` for polish language) .

For example you can see how it is done for spanish [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/facebook/res/values-es/strings.xml).

Comment: So there is no other option?

Comment: ale tam są wszystkie 3 napisy `Logged in as: %1$s`, `Cancel` i `Log out` co chcesz osiągnąć?